# Why is there only one group of order $n$ for some non-primes?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I would like to understand for which integers $n$ is there only one group of order $n$. (up to isomorphism).

I understand that if $n$ is prime there is only one group of order $n$.  In Sloane's [OEIS A003277](https://oeis.org/search?q=A003277) we see the primes along with: $1, 15, 33, 35, 51, 65, 69, 77, 85, 87, 91, 95, \cdots$.  We are told that there is only one group of order $n$ for integers in this sequence.  There are several characterizations of these numbers: Integers $n$ such that $x^n \equiv1$ (mod $n$) has no solution $2 \leq x \leq n$.  Integers $n$ such that gcd($\varphi(n),n)=1$.  Integers $n = p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdots p_k$ where no $p_i$ divides $p_{j - 1}$.

Would any of these characterizations be used in a proof that there is only one group of order $n$ for $n$ in A003277?

Comment: There is only one group of order $n$ if and only if gcd($\varphi(n),n)=1$. Your characterizations are even equivalences.

Comment: @Ge Apparently you haven't yet studied Sylow's Theorems (otherwise the answer would be clear), so perhaps wait a little until then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is a group of order $pq$ where $p>q$ are prime and $q$ doesn't divide $p-1$ then $G$ is cyclic.(application of Sylow's theorem).

Comment: @ Anubha, thanks, but this doesn't help my understanding.  You are just stating a theorem.  Also remember that these integers can have more than 2 distinct prime factors.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer The proof is immediate from Sylow's theorems, and generalizes to the case of multiple prime factors.

Comment: OK thanks Anubha, Slade, Nicky, and Timbuc.  I think I am asking a question that I am not prepared to understand the answer to yet.  I will try to research the Sylow theorems.