# Are there conditions for the uniqueness, up to isomorphism, of the groups of a given order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

We know by Lagrange's theorem of groups implies that any group of order $p$, where $p$ is prime, is *unique up to isomorphism*. Moreover, there are non-prime numbers $n$ such that exist only one group of order $n$ up to isomorphism; for example $15$ and $33$. My question is:

> Are there conditions for the uniqueness, up to isomorphism, of the groups of a given order?

**Edit:** By Sylow's theorems it is well known that if $G$ is a group of order $pq$, where $p > q$ are primes, and $q \nmid p-1$ then $G$ is a cyclic group and thus the only group of this order up to isomorphism.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there only one group of order $n$ for some non-primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240939/why-is-there-only-one-group-of-order-n-for-some-non-primes)

Comment: Also see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/148731/for-which-n-is-there-only-one-group-of-order-n

Comment: By the way, I had no trouble finding these by doing a search for `only one group of order n`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MJD!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. A natural number $n$ has the property you want if and only if $\gcd(n,\varphi(n))=1$, where $\varphi$ is the familiar totient function of Euler. Such numbers are known as cyclic numbers.

Comment: Thank you @the_fox, Could you give me a short proof about that?

Comment: It does not have a short proof (well, one direction of the equivalence does not have a short proof).  I wrote up a proof at https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/allgrouporderncyclic.pdf.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it!